# Como solucionar System.IO.IOException: 'El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, .asmx

Tengo un Webservice el cual carga documentos adjuntos al servidor, en mi desarrollo tengo dos formularios los cuales cargan documentos haciendo llamado al mismo Webservice, el codigo de mi Webservice es el siguiente:

```
[WebMethod]
        public void UploadFile(FileData fileData)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileData.Name))
            {

                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileData.Data);
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("//Files/");
                foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    file.Delete();
                }              
                var copyToPath = "//Files/" + fileData.Name;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes((copyToPath), imageBytes);
            }
        }

        public class FileData
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Data { get; set; }
        }
```

El error sucede cuando cargo documentos en el primer formulario e inmediatamente cargo documentos en el otro.

Al parecer el proceso sigue ejecutándose, no se si existe manera de terminar el proceso o de hacer un reload para que no tenga en cuenta el anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estas tratando de invocar el mismo archivo desde dos procesos completamente diferentes, la solución que podrías aplicar es esperar a que el archivo lo libere el primer proceso para que lo pueda ocupar el segundo proceso, con este código:

```
public static bool IsFileReady(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
            return inputStream.Length > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

y lo usarías de la siguiente manera:

```
[WebMethod]
    public void UploadFile(FileData fileData)
    {
     
        while (!IsFileReady(fileData.Name)) {  }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileData.Name))
        {

            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileData.Data);
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("//Files/");
            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }              
            var copyToPath = "//Files/" + fileData.Name;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes((copyToPath), imageBytes);
        }
    }
```

Espero te funcione, saludos!

Comment: No se declara nada dentro del While ?

Comment: no, lo que necesitas es que termine el while (que espere hasta que se desocupe el proceso). Lo que también te sugiero es que busques alternativas y formas para evitar llegar a estos casos, saludos y mucho éxito!